# convert select component in material ui from fuction to class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am new to react and am using the select button of material-ui. I am trying to use the select component but am using a class component. The code in material ui page gives this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import NativeSelect from '@material-ui/core/NativeSelect';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

export default function NativeSelects() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    age: '',
    name: 'hai',
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    setState({
      ...state,
      [name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          native
          value={state.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps={{
            name: 'age',
            id: 'age-native-simple',
          }}
        >
          <option aria-label="None" value="" />
          <option value={10}>Ten</option>
          <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
          <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

How do I convert it in a class component. I am having trouble in classes.formControl.

Could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: More and more people use functional components with hooks. Why go all the way back to class component? New library and API in the future tend to use hooks instead of HOC. You should prefer functional component over class component when writing new code or you will be left behind.

Comment: Yes agreed but do you have a solution to the problem

Comment: Can you add the last part of the code. It's cut off at the end

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can convert except classes thing. You can take help of material style `hoc` api. For your case `withTheme` is sufficient. Here is the more [reference](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/)

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import NativeSelect from "@material-ui/core/NativeSelect";

class NativeSelects extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const classes = {
      formControl: {
        margin: this.props.theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120,
      },
      selectEmpty: {
        marginTop: this.props.theme.spacing(2),
      },
    };
    return (
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor='age-native-simple'>Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          native
          value={state.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps={{
            name: "age",
            id: "age-native-simple",
          }}
        >
          <option aria-label='None' value='' />
          <option value={10}>Ten</option>
          <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
          <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
  }
}

export default withTheme(NativeSelects);
```

Comment: margin: this.props.theme.spacing(1), When I added the code it was showing the error 
  ,Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: I dont see any issue. Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-wind-vsft7?file=/src/App.js:0-1454

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withStyles` instead of `makeStyles` for class component

```
import React from "react";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

class NativeSelectsClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      age: "",
      name: "hai"
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const handleChange = (event) => {
      const name = event.target.name;
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [name]: event.target.value
      });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">Age</InputLabel>
          <Select
            native
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={handleChange}
            inputProps={{
              name: "age",
              id: "age-native-simple"
            }}
          >
            <option aria-label="None" value="" />
            <option value={10}>Ten</option>
            <option value={20}>Twenty</option>
            <option value={30}>Thirty</option>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = (theme) => {
  return {
    formControl: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      minWidth: 120
    },
    selectEmpty: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
    }
  };
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NativeSelectsClass);
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit React Material-UI WithStyle]